# How to differentiate when to use angular expression inside any of it's directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am confused about when to use expressions and when not to use inside default AngularJS directives such as **ng-src**, **ng-href** and other.

According to my understanding when we use angular directive we have just use scope variable names to bind it's value. Following expression work properly.

`<link ng-href="{{BASIC_PATH + '/relative-path-url/image.png'}}"/>`

But consider an case of **ng-model** directive, following example is not valid way to bind variables.

`<span ng-model="{{BASIC_PATH}}"></span>`

Every time when I have to use angular expressions with directives, I used to write code in both format and then test. 
So what is the basic fundamental way to use expressions with angular directives.

Comment: I normally read documentation on the directive and see how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Using the {{ }} tells Angular to evaluate the variable and pass its value to the directive.

So if your controller contains the line:

```
$scope.myVar = "test";
```

Then this line:

```
<input ng-model="{{myVar}}">
```

Would basically be compiled to:

```
<input ng-model="'test'">
```

Therefore, the way to remember which convention you should use, is to ask yourself if the directive wants the variable itself, or the value of the variable.